# Swift error, Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
@State var message: String = ""

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                TextEditor(text: Binding($message))
                    .frame(minHeight: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    .cornerRadius(6.0)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Text(message ?? "Message")
                    .padding(.leading, 4)
                    .opacity(message == "" ? 1 : 0)
                }
                .font(.body)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to execute the code, it says `"Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'"` next to `TextEditor(text: Binding($message)` Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Remove the `Binding()`. Just use `TextEditor(text: $message)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is originated from this line

```
Text(message ?? "Message")
```

because compiler tries to infer type and this line shows that type should be optional, but editor expects not optional, so you got conflict and error. Your `message` state is not optional so you just need to move default value directly in intializer.

Here is corrected variant:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State var message: String = "Message"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                TextEditor(text: $message)
                    .frame(minHeight: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    .cornerRadius(6.0)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Text(message)
                    .padding(.leading, 4)
                    .opacity(message == "" ? 1 : 0)
            }
            .font(.body)
        }
    }
}
```